# Xcode compilation on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am writing an iPhone app and working with `Xcode SDK 3.1.2`.
My iPhone device has `iOS version 3.1.2` and also the debugging is working well.
The problem now is with my new iPad; the iOS version on the iPad is `4.2`. 
So what do I need to do to debug with the iPad, as well?
Do I need to upgrade the Xcode SDK to `4.2`? If I do so, does it generate problems with the app compilation? Because the code writing was finished.

What I know is that I can't update the iOS version on my iPhone. I have to stay with `3.1.2` on that iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to upgrade your XCode to the newest version, which is included in the iOS 4.2 SDK.

You cannot use an older SDK (in essence an older version of XCode) to compile for a newer version of iOS, but you can use a newer version of XCode and compile for older versions of iOS. You just need to set the "Base SDK" to whatever you want, in the project settings (topmost file in the "groups and files" pane on the left, with the blue icon, press "get info" on that one).

To give you an example, you can use iOS SDK 4.2 to develop, deploy and release for say an iPhone running iOS 3.1.2. On the other hand, you cannot use iOS SDK 3.2 to develop for an iPhone (or iPad) running iOS 4.2.

tldr: update your XCode and change your Base SDK settings and you will be on your way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to download the newest SDK. You will need it anyway to build new version for your iPhone app because Apple requires App Store submissions to be built for iOS 4.x (Base SDK).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use iOS 4.2 SDK to build and compile, but you can set iOS 3.0 as the desired OS of deployment. Thus you will be able to test your app on the iPhone you have and the iPad.

To do so, edit the settings of your target by selecting it and right clicking 'info'. On the build settings tab, you will see a lot of settings. Two of these are interesting to you: first one on the first level set the 'base sdk' for build to latest SDK. Then look for "iOS deployment target" and set iOS 3.1.

Have fun.